# Automate Credential creation on build servers for VSTS Nuget feeds

Tags: tfsbuild, nuget-package, tfs-2015, azure-artifacts

We are in a state of having both on premises TFS as well as utilizing VSTS. Mainly nuget feeds, but some source is migrating.

In the meantime getting/publishing nuget feeds is happening on our on premises build servers. I was able to run their Auth tool which gave one server a vss token to get and publish to VSTS, but that takes me through the GUI login for VSTS. I know nuget supports this new Credential management tool, but I've not found a way to script that yet.

Is there an automated way, powershell preferably, to provide the VSTS to publish packages? Or did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

In a build environment, using the [VSTS Auth Helper](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/auth#vsts-auth-helper) is the right way to go. You'll want to use the `-NonInteractive` flag to avoid the web prompt.

If your organization has enabled two-factor authentication, the build service account will need an exception for the `-NonInteractive` flag to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is supported through a combination of Visual Studio Credential Provider and [nuget.exe](http://nuget.org/downloads). Detailed instrcutions on how to enable this is given is give [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/auth).